# I need to filter products by date from a database table with date attached. This will be added to a dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql

*Modified* no joy with this but i don't think we're too far off. what could i improve?

```
<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Date</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">       
                    <?php $d = strtotime("today"); ?>
                    <a href="?date=lastWeek"><option value="1">Last 7 days</option></a>
                    <a href="?date=lastMonth"><option value="2">Last 30 days</option></a>
                    <a href="?date=date"><option value="3">Last 3 months</option></a>
                    <a href="?date=date"><option value="4">Last 12 months</option></a>

                </div>
            </div>

if (isset($_GET["date"])) {
            $date = ($_GET['date']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE date created BETWEEN '2017-08-18' AND '$d'" . $date . "'";
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Comment: Could you show us your full code for this? The bit that throws the error isn't in your code sample.

Comment: Also, injecting your GET parameter directly into your query leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks. Have a look here on how to avoid that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the date parameter and quote it, or use bound parameters, which are much safer.

```
if (isset($_GET["date"])) {
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['date']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE date = '" . $date . "'";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts ORDER BY id ASC";
}
```

OR if you're using PDO:

```
if (isset($_GET["date"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE date = :date";
    $connection->prepare($sql);
    $connection->bindParam(':date', $_GET['date']);
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts ORDER BY id ASC";
}
```